# React-Select creatable event handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am working with  [Creatable](https://react-select.com/creatable)  multi select component, to manage an email list. I have two almost similar components to work with email To list and CC list.
I made it mostly work using doc and other online resources and examples. But each time a new requirement comes I am struggling to figure out a solution. So I thought if I can get answers to these basic question that will help me a lot.

1. How do I know what value is being passed on to the handlers
   For example here onChange={handleChangeCC}
   onChange is passing the current values of the component to handleChangeCC. But where can I get that info if I want to work on another event?
2. Is there a way to get the origin component in an eventhandler? In my case both handleChangeCC and handleChangeTo do almost the same thing. So, if I know the component that called this handler I can use the same handler to handle both CC component and To component.
3. Is there are list of all the props and event handlers of the creatable component? I know there is this [doc](https://react-select.com/props) but hard time understanding it. Any help in making sense of that document will be very helpful.

I understand these questions arise since I am a beginner to javascript and React, but please help me to figure out these syntaxes and more

This is the how I defined the component

```
  <CreatableSelect
                  isMulti
                  options={emailOptions}
                  value={toEmailList}
                  onChange={ handleChangeTo }
                  isDisabled={disable()}
                />
```